# Library comments in Altium Library components don't hide when toggling the option

Tags: schematics, altium

I'm using version 20.2.4 of Altium Designer.

I have several libraries with hand-made component schematics. These components have a Designator, a Comment and a Description, but I only want to see the designator when I use them on a new schematic. Therefore, I toggle the hide option (symbol of an eye) in the library, because I don't want to do it every time I use the component. After that, something strange happens, and although I have selected the hide option in the library, it's unselected in the schematic sheet when I place the component.

[image]

It's really annoying, and I think it's a kind of a bug. If someone knows something about this, I'd be very grateful to read an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take it up with Altium, but I never managed to disable it either. What I ended up doing is:

If I wanted a significant comment, I used fields. The best example is for resistors. I wanted their value with the tolerance. The description would then be "=value+"+/-"+tolerance+"%". That way, all the comments are significant on the schematic.

If I don't want a comment, I usually set the description to =" ". Since it's not a significant field anyway, I don't mind having it with a space in it.

If I want a comment but not to see it, what I did is on the symbol, I display the refdef and description (It's an  option in the visual setting of the symbol) and set the font to something very small and the color of my component. Then I placed it somewhere no one would see and locked it. I also checked the box to not autoposition it.

You could also open a ticket with Altium for that issue. I kinda got used to it and now it doesn't really bother me anymore.